Expanding the superpotential in terms of its components
A chiral superfield in component form is defined as:
$$\Phi(x,\theta,\bar\theta)=\phi(x)+\sqrt{2}\theta\psi(x)+\theta^2 F(x) + i\theta\sigma^\mu \bar\theta\partial_\mu \phi(x) - \frac{i}{\sqrt2} \theta^2 \partial_\mu\phi(x)\sigma^\mu\bar\theta - \frac{1}{4} \theta^2 \bar\theta^2\Box\phi(x)$$
where $\Box =\partial_\mu\partial^\mu$.
The superpotential $W(\Phi)$ is a holomorphic function of the chiral superfield and is itself a chrial superfiled. How does one expand the super potential in terms of its components to get it in the form below?
$$W(\Phi) = W(\phi) + \sqrt2 \frac{\partial{W}}{\partial{\phi}}\theta\psi + \theta^2(\frac{\partial{W}}{\partial\phi}F-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 W}{\partial\phi^2}\psi\psi)+...$$

isn't it just the Taylor expansion? $\Phi=\phi +\epsilon$, so $W(\Phi) =W(\phi) + W'(\phi)\epsilon + W''(\phi)\epsilon^2/2+\dots$
